# mvn deploy json-lib to neuxs is wrong

Tags: maven

Company server can not even outside the network, now need to json-lib jar package to nexus

> mvn deploy:deploy-file -Durl=http://ip:port/repository/maven-releases -DrepositoryId=nexus -DgeneratePom=false -DpomFile=json-lib-2.4.pom -Dpackaging=jar  -Dfile=json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar -DgroupId=net.sf.json-lib -DartifactId=json-lib

json-lib

[image: json-lib]

But spread to nexus, found jar package file name is wrong, as shown below

uploading.

[image: uploading]

nexus

[image: nexus]

How can I operate the jar correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to check the version inside the json-lib-2.4.pom or add a "-Dversion=2.4-jdk15"